# Is the expression "see you soon" impolite when I send email to superiors?

Tags: expressions

Are there some polite expressions on "see you soon"?

Comment: 'I hope to see you soon' sounds less presumptuous. 'See you soon' is over-familiar unless you are addressing someone you know intimately, or using a very informal register for another reason.

Comment: You should not be afraid of speaking to your superiors like human beings. It depends on the politics of your organisation, and the working relationship you have with your superiors. If you are on friendly terms, 'see you soon' is perfectly fine, in fact stuffiness in emails can come across as very out of place. However if it's someone a few grades above you, for example who you have never met, see you soon, wouldn't work well, it's too informal. "I look forward to meeting soon" would work well enough.

Answer (score 5):

You could certainly make the comment feel more formal.  Length usually implies formality, so adding in some of the implicit words might help, or perhaps choosing different words.  Even adding one word can feel less casual: "I'll see you soon."

If it's intended to be a workplace-polite way of saying, "this is the end of my message and I'd like to emphasize that I feel positive about our upcoming joint project/venture/meeting," I'd probably go with something more specific to the situation, such as "Looking forward to our meeting," or "I'll see you in the conference room."

If it's just a quick acknowledgement that you're about to meet them to discuss something non-critical, but you want to sound businesslike, then maybe "I'll be there shortly," or "I'll see you in a moment."

If you wish to communicate that you are doing as told, then perhaps you'd say, "I'll be there promptly," "I'm on my way," or "I'll be right there."  In some jobs, where obedience is expected, you might add "sir" or some other contextually-appropriate label.

Comment: You're welcome!  If you're satisfied, then remember to mark your question answered.  You can either mark mine as the answer, or wait to see if anyone has a better answer.  Either way, good luck at work.  :)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, but I don't know how to mark my question answered. :( Because I started today. Can you teach me how to mark it?

Comment: Oh, if I remember correctly, there's a button below the vote-up/down arrows on my answer where you can click (a check mark, I think?) that sets it as your accepted answer.  But don't worry if you can't, it's not a big deal.  People usually go by the number of votes an answer gets anyway, but sometimes it's nice to know which one was chosen by the person who asked, that's all.